# How to update database from unchanged datatable

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I want to update my server database from my local database

```
Dim mycon As New SqlConnection(myserverConString)
Dim myAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE", mycon)
Dim mybuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(myAdapter)
myAdapter.UpdateCommand = mybuilder.GetUpdateCommand(True)
dim dt as datatable 
'code to fill dt from my local db
'using select statement
For Each DR As DataRow In dt.Rows
   DR.SetModified()
Next
dt.AcceptChanges()
myAdapter.Update(dt)
```

the problem is the used datatable in fact contain no changes
and the command builder updatecommand use the wrong "where"
I found the used update command is

```
UPDATE [MYTABLE] SET [COLUMN0] = @COLUMN0, [COLUMN1]=@COLUMN1 WHERE 
([COLUMN0]=@Original_COLUMN0) AND ([COLUMN1]=@Original_COLUMN1))
```

COLUNM0 IS THE PRIMARY KEY

COLUMN1 IS THE UPDATED VALUE IN THE LOCAL DB,

AND I WANT TO UPDATE IT IN THE SERVER DB WHICH IS THE SAME SCHEMA.

COLUMN1 CAN'T used in "WHERE clause " as it is the changed value

and the dt doesn't have an original value for it.

My code doesn't give any errors,

but it also doesn't update anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer,
just added one line of code before update statement

```
dt=dt.getchanges()
myAdapter.update(dt)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating from your local DB why check the value of `COLUMN1` in the `WHERE` clause? Just update all rows to the local `COLUMN1` value.

Just use

```
UPDATE [MYTABLE] 
SET [COLUMN1] = @COLUMN1 
WHERE [COLUMN0] = @Original_COLUMN0
```

**EDIT:** You may well be better off adding a timestamp to your rows to make it easier for the SqlCommandBuilder to detect changes.

From [The SQLCommandBuilder is way Better than its Reputation](http://petermeinl.wordpress.com/2011/03/13/the-sqlcommandbuilder-is-way-better-than-its-reputation/)

> The SQLCommandBuilder supports different ConflictOptions to detect
>   optimistic update conflicts:
>
> OverwriteChanges (= no control) CompareAllSearchableValues (compares
>   the values of all searchable columns) CompareRowVersion (compares the
>   value the column with datatype RowVersion (~Timestamp) I prefer using
>   CompareRowVersion. See DB Concurrency Control with .NET-Details.

Also have a read of [DB Concurrency Control with .NET – Details](http://petermeinl.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/db-concurrency-control-patterns-for-applications/) to see how to do this.

Comment: this update statement the builder generate not me , it use where as the dt contain many records.

Comment: Notice the "@Original_" part of the COLUMN1 variable in the `WHERE` clause? You need to pass in the value it was _before_ it was changed. Do you have that anywhere?

Comment: Do you **have** to use the `SqlCommandBuilder` for such a simple update, why not write the SQL query yourself?

Comment: to get it I must compare local db with server one, record by record, but I want to use 'adapter.update(dt)'

Comment: It seems the `SqlCommandBuilder` is expecting you to have changed either `COLUMN0` or `COLUMN1`, or both. You are going to need to know the value of both columns _before_ the local DB was changed so you can pass them in to the query.